# Assign values to variables inside a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, insert

I am having a complex MySQL Trigger, which I would like to simplify at the moment. Below is the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Ongoing_Portfolio_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Ongoing_Portfolio` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Portfolio
    SET Invest_Amount = New.Investment_Value,
    Cash_Value = New.Cash_Value,
    Date_Of_Last_Update = New.Updated_Date
    WHERE idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;

    INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Gross_Fee, Insurance_Fee, Submit_Fee)
    SELECT current_timestamp,
    New.Gross_Fee,
    (New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100),
    ((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100))-(p.s_Fee/100)
    FROM Portfolio p
    WHERE p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
END;
```

What you see here is just a part, there is much more.

You can see the lines like,

1. `(New.Gross_Fee)*(p.i_Fee/100)`
2. `((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.i_Fee/100))-(p.s/100)`

Actually, the

1. `Insurance_Fee` -  is % amount of `New.Gross_Fee`
2. `Submit_Fee` - is `Insurance_Fee- (p.s_Fee/100)`

I would like to introduce variables for this purpose, rather than writing these long calculations. So the variables will be something like

1. `_InsuranceFee := (New.Gross_Fee)*(p.i_Fee/100)`
2. `_SubmitFee := _InsuranceFee - (p.s_Fee/100)`

This kind of work will short the calculations and of course easy to read. But, as you can see, my "Insert" query is actually using a `Select` query. It is because all the "Percentage" values are coming from table `Portfolio` (alias `p`) So how can I assign values to variables and directly insert them to the DB while inside the `Select` query?

Or else, any other way to assign the values to variables, so I can just use the variables in select query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using local variables?

```
declare `_InsuranceFee`, `_SubmitFee` decimal(10, 4);

INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Gross_Fee, Insurance_Fee, Submit_Fee)
    SELECT current_timestamp, New.Gross_Fee,
           `_InsuranceFee` := (New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100),
           `_SubmitFee` := ((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100))-(p.s_Fee/100)
    FROM Portfolio p
    WHERE p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
```

Comment: You have again used the same line of code i wanted to avoid ' `_SubmitFee` := ((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100))-(p.s_Fee/100)'

Comment: I want to re-use the variables.

Comment: @Sniper . . . There should be no issue re-using the variables inside the trigger.  Is the issue that you don't want to repeat the expression for `_SubmitFree`?

Comment: Hi, I just tried this. using ``_InsuranceFee` := (New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100),` simply generated `syntax error. Unexpected SET_VAR expecting ;`